# Не срабатывают события на форме при раскрытом ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, combobox, dropdown

Нужно сделать кнопки на форме, которые будут переходить по элементам `ComboBox` (аналог клавиш клавиатуры "Вверх" и "Вниз"). Причём нужно это делать на раскрытом `ComboBox`.
Как только `ComboBox`, события контролов формы не срабатывают. При клике на контрол формы сворачивается `ComboBox`. Только следующий клик вызывает событие Click контрола. Подозреваю, что это из-за того, что фокус переходит к форме-раскрытому списку. Если принудительно вызвать `Focus()` для формы, на которой расположен `ComboBox`, список сворачивается.
Как сделать так, чтобы и список был раскрыт, и отрабатывался клик на контролах формы?
Использую WinForms в .Net CF 2.0 (для WinCE 6.0).

Comment: Использовать `ListBox`

Comment: @Igor, с `ListBox` всё работает, но нужен именно выпадающий список. Более того, всё отлично (переход между `Items`) работает и для `ComboBox`, если его не раскрывать. Или вы предлагаете выводить новый `ListBox` вместо того, чтобы раскрывать `ComboBox`? Средствами `ComboBox` этого не сделаешь?

Comment: Можете поэкспериментировать со свойством `ComboBox.DroppedDown`. Но там, кажется, нужно постоянно устанавливать фокус на `ComboBox`. Не знаю, будет ли изображение мелькать. Вообще, требование немного странное - оно противоречит тому, как работает этот контрол Windows.

Comment: @Igor , согласен про Windows, но тут имеем дело с Windows CE и аналогом пользовательской тач-клавиатуре на форме.
В .Net CF у `ComboBox` нет свойства `ComboBox.DroppedDown`. Узнаю о том, раскрыт или нет этот контрол через сообщения WindowsCE Forms.